# Multiple Hyperlinks to Multiple Pages in rich text box c#

Tags: c#, hyperlink, richtextbox

There's an unknown amount of links in a richtextbox at one time... I'm populating tickets into a windows form based on a sql query.. so I want the user to click on a link and take them to the website page (aka the ticket)

So each link would be like ..

"http://.Ticket.com/Ticket1"
"http://.Ticket.com/Ticket4"
ect..
(nothing will be in numerical order)

Any thoughts on how to handle the links? I have the SQL ect down just need an idea on how to correlate the links stored with what is started in IE.

This is just a working example:

```
            richTickets.Text = "http://www.ticket.com";

            richTickets.LinkClicked += new System.Windows.Forms.LinkClickedEventHandler(richTextBox1_LinkClicked);

public System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

    private void richTextBox1_LinkClicked(object sender,
    System.Windows.Forms.LinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Call Process.Start method to open a browser
        // with link text as URL.
        p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "http://www.ticket.com");


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LinkClickedEventArgs` argument `e` contains a [`LinkText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linkclickedeventargs.linktext(v=vs.110).aspx) property which is the URL that was clicked - so you can use that as the parameter in your process start call.

```c#
 private void richTextBox1_LinkClicked(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.LinkClickedEventArgs e)
 {
     p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.LinkText);
 }
```